# mod_rewrite with previous rule affecting other rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the next `RewriteRule` for being able of access to

```
domain.com/section/products/whatever
```

from the folder called `_products`. The original URL looks like this:

```
domain.com/section/_products/product.php?param=whatever
```

This is that rule:

```
RewriteRule ^section/products/(.*)$ section/_products/$1 [L,NC]
```

---

Now I need to rewrite this URL:

```
domain.com/section/products/brand/index.php?brand=apple
```

To this one:

```
domain.com/section/products/brand/apple
```

I'm trying with this:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^section/products/(.*)$ section/_products/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(section/products/brand)/([\w-]+)$ /section/_products/brand/index.php?brand=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Also with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(section/products/brand)/([\w-]+)$ /section/products/brand/index.php?brand=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

None of those two are working for me.

Should the `section/_products/$1` rule go after or before the other rule?
I can't find the right logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(section/products/brand)/([^/]+)$ $1/index.php?brand=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(section)/products/(.*)$ $1/_products/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: The first rule worked for me, but replacing the second rule for what I already have makes the server throw a 500 error. Thanks!

Comment: But looks like it doesn't accept spaces? I have some `?brand=` with spaces (`%20à doesn't work in URL).

Comment: I've solved it with this regex: `([\w-\s]+)$` Thank you!